# Side job proposal but I am already busy

Tags: freelancing, projects

I am a Masters degree student in Machine Learning almost finishing my degree (I'm expecting to deliver my dissertation by March of 2019, but currently I have no plans of pursuing a PhD). Currently, I am also working on a moderately difficult side project which pays considerably well and it's expected to last until the end of 2019.

Today a senior guy from my lab offered me to work on one more side project for the same salary, which will double my (somewhat) good income. The project seems to be simple, pretty much web scraping, but it's also expected to last until the end of the next year.

I am tempted to take it as well, but I am afraid of not being able to fulfill all my commitments due to the amount of work that I'll have to handle, since I really want to finish my Masters by March (basically I still have to run a bunch of experiments and write the experimental and results section of my dissertation). Also, I think some "unexpected" requirements may appear during the development of this another project.

What do you guys think? Should I take it, since

1. The project seems to be easy;
2. It pays well
3. There is going to be another guy working with me, but I think that he's less qualified than me

Although:

1. I already have a lot of things to do
2. I am afraid of committing myself to more than I can do

If it is of interest, I plan to finish my Masters and then look for a regular job instead of relying on projects for my main source of income.

Comment: Did you ask him if the side-project ***must** start immediately, or if it can wait four short months until March? It might well be that if you commit he will accept a delay.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start with figuring out your priorities. Having mentioned that you plan to search for a regular job after your Masters, it sounds ill-advised to already have a lot on your plate as you go job searching.

Do you really want to find a regular job right away, or do you want to take advantage of these side project opportunities you have now?

You already have a side project going on, so adding another one might end hindering your job searching efforts, and even if you end up with a regular full-time job, having to juggle that with your personal projects sounds quite hectic.

Now if you really want to consider taking this new project on offer, your decision will depend on how well you can manage your time working on this new project. Consider what possible developments may come up over the course of that project you're offered, and see how it fits your workload right now.

Don't overestimate your limits as you may just end up negatively affecting your Masters and your current project.